# Why is my server using swap even though there is lots of RAM available?

Tags: performance, memory, memory-usage, swap, virtual-memory

My server has 24 cores, 16 GB RAM, and 8 SSDs on raid 0 (I think).

I've noticed it is now using a low of swap space, even though there is plenty of RAM available.

```
load average: 2.70, 2.54, 2.50
Mem:  16303072k total,  1546160k used, 14756912k free,     9200k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,   471084k used,  1626060k free,   552448k cached
```

Do you know what could be causing something like this and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Depends on the workload. The cache is telling me that something ran that ate up tons of RAM, then stopped. Your load average tells me that this server is doing *something*. What do you use it for?

Comment: Why would you fix something that is not broken?

Comment: As the Nathan C said. Some software ran that used huge amount of RAM, and then stopped. What you can think about, is that maybe for database got a huge burst of queries in short time, or your website got unusual amount of visits?

Comment: There _isn't_ lots of RAM available.

Comment: take a look at - http://www.linuxatemyram.com/